# Asterisk.net originate not ringing exten

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am using asterisk Management Interface, trying to originate a call to an external phone from an internal one.
The originate action makes the internal phone ring, but when it is picked up, the line is blank and the external phone doesnt ring.

I'm using the standard sample as follows:

```
Dim m As New Asterisk.NET.Manager.ManagerConnection
m.Hostname = "123.123.123.123"
m.Port = 5038
m.Username = "me"`enter code here`
m.Password = "secret"
m.Login()
Dim o2 As New Asterisk.NET.Manager.Action.OriginateAction
o2.CallerId = "01234567890"
o2.Channel = "SIP/101"  'office extension 101
o2.Context = "ext-local"
o2.Exten = "07910123456 'my mobile
o2.Priority = 1
o2.Timeout = 30000
o2.ActionId = "Test" & Now.ToString("yyyymmddhhMMss")
Dim r = m.SendAction(o2, 30000)
```

Office extension 101 rings (great!) we pick it up and the line is dead. My mobile doesnt ring (not great)

Ive reproduced exactly the same thing with telnet, with exactly the same result.

Any suggestions or pointers greatfully received.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1) Read nice asterisk book, for example "Asterisk the future of telephony". Without understanding dialplan no way go forth.

2) Check that you have context ext-local and it have extension specified

```
asterisk -rx "dialplan show 07910123456@ext-local
```

3) Connect to asterisk console and see dialplan execution. If not help, check sip debug.